# Scratch Org Error while Creating

Tags: salesforcedx, scratch-org

Can't create scratch org from org shape:

> The org shape version is outdated. Recreate the org shape and try again

Comment: Does anyone have any insights about the above error?

Comment: I'd guess you need a new org shape that is compatible with Winter 24?

Comment: You might be seeing SH-0003 error when you try to create scratch org, try to re-create new org shape version and that should resolve the issue. (https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_scratch_orgs_error_codes.htm)